# How can I set up two different types on VPN servers on the same machine?

Tags: debian, vpn

I have configured an IKEv2 VPN server on my debian machine to have a VPN for my BlackBerry (which supports IKEv2 **only** as a "consumer grade" VPN). I would like to connect my Windows 7 PC to this VPN but is not possible as the VPN requires a PSK authentication which Windows 7 does not support.

Do I have to run two istances of `strongswan` on the same machine to I have one IKEv2 VPN server (for my BlackBerry) and one L2TP VPN server (for my Windows 7 PC)? If yes, how can I run two istances of `strongswan`?

Any other solution is very welcone.